# base64.decode: Invalid encoding before padding

Tags: string, flutter, dart, base64, decode

I'm working on a flutter project and I'm currently getting an error with some of the strings I try do decode using the base64.decode() method. I've created a short dart code which can reproduce the problem I'm facing with a specific string:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final message = 'RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==';
  print(utf8.decode(base64.decode(message)));
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: FormatException: Invalid encoding before padding (at character 19)
RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==
```

I've tried decoding the same string with JavaScript and it works fine. Would be glad if someone could explain why am I getting this error, and possibly show me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding breaks binary data into 6-bit segments of 3 full bytes and represents those as printable characters in ASCII standard. It does that in essentially two steps.

The first step is to break the binary string down into 6-bit blocks. Base64 only uses 6 bits (corresponding to 2^6 = 64 characters) to ensure encoded data is printable and humanly readable. None of the special characters available in ASCII are used.

The 64 characters (hence the name Base64) are 10 digits, 26 lowercase characters, 26 uppercase characters as well as the Plus sign (+) and the Forward Slash (/). There is also a 65th character known as a pad, which is the Equal sign (=). This character is used when the last segment of binary data doesn't contain a full 6 bits

So RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1== doesn't follow the encoding pattern.

Comment: You are wrong stating that `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==` doesn't follow the encoding pattern. Otherwise, tell me why `base64.b64decode('RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==').decode()` returns `'ENTREGAGRATIS'` in Python (and works in `.NET` as well), and the OP confirms that it works fine in JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. But as Josef said, I've tryied to decode it using other languages as well and it did decode without a problem. Also when I run isBase64 it returns true, so I can't see why I get the error.

Comment: @JosefZ, I did a bit study on it and found that it really doesn't follow the pattern, maybe dart is not that powerful to convert or understand this hashkey. this is what I found in dart:convert,

*/// Checks that [_state] represents a valid decoding.
  void close(String? input, int? end) {
    if (_state < _encodePaddingState(0)) {
      throw FormatException("Missing padding character", input, end);
    }
    if (_state > 0) {
      throw FormatException(
          "Invalid length, must be multiple of four", input, end);
    }
    _state = _encodePaddingState(0);
  }*

Comment: I'll mess with the string and see what I can do about the encoding then. Thank you again for the effort. I'll come back again later when I find a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Underline character "_" as Padding Character and Decode With Pad Bytes Deleted

For some reason `dart:convert`'s `base64.decode` chokes on strings padded with `=` with the "invalid encoding before padding error". This happens even if you use the package's own padding method `base64.normalize` which pads the string with the correct padding character `=`.

`=` is indeed the correct padding character for base64 encoding. It is used to fill out base64 strings when fewer than 24 bits are available in the input group. See [RFC 4648, Section 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-4).

However, [RFC 4648 Section 5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5) which is a base64 encoding scheme for Urls uses the underline character `_` as padding instead of `=` to be Url safe.

Using `_` as the padding character will cause `base64.decode` to decode without error.

In order to further decode the generated list of bytes to Utf8, you will need to delete the padding bytes or you will get an "Invalid UTF-8 byte" error.

See the code below. [Here is the same code as a working dartpad.dev example.](https://dartpad.dev/?id=dc595442154a95a686c60c91ef035018)

```
    import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  //String message = 'RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1=='; //as of dart 2.18.2 this will generate an "invalid encoding before padding" error
  //String message = base64.normalize('RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1'); // will also generate same error

  String message = 'RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1';
  print("Encoded String: $message");
  print("Decoded String: ${decodeB64ToUtf8(message)}");
}

decodeB64ToUtf8(String message) {
  message =
      padBase64(message); // pad with underline => ('RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1__')
  List<int> dec = base64.decode(message);
  //remove padding bytes
  dec = dec.sublist(0, dec.length - RegExp(r'_').allMatches(message).length);
  return utf8.decode(dec);
}

String padBase64(String rawBase64) {
  return (rawBase64.length % 4 > 0)
      ? rawBase64 += List.filled(4 - (rawBase64.length % 4), "_").join("")
      : rawBase64;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==` is not a compliant base 64 encoding according to [RFC 4648](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt), which in section 3.5, "Canonical Encoding," states:

> The padding step in base 64 and base 32 encoding can, if improperly
> implemented, lead to non-significant alterations of the encoded data.
> For example, if the input is only one octet for a base 64 encoding,
> then all six bits of the first symbol are used, but only the first
> two bits of the next symbol are used.  **These pad bits MUST be set to
> zero by conforming encoders**, which is described in the descriptions
> on padding below.  If this property do not hold, there is no
> canonical representation of base-encoded data, and multiple base-
> encoded strings can be decoded to the same binary data.  If this
> property (and others discussed in this document) holds, a canonical
> encoding is guaranteed.
>
> In some environments, the alteration is critical and therefore
> decoders MAY chose to reject an encoding if the pad bits have not
> been set to zero.  The specification referring to this may mandate a
> specific behaviour.

(Emphasis added.)

Here we will manually go through the base 64 decoding process.

Taking your encoded string `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==` and performing the mapping from the base 64 character set (given in "Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet" of the aforementioned RFC), we have:

```
  R      U      5      U      U      k      V      H      Q      U      d      S      Q      V      R      J      U      1      =       =
010001 010100 111001 010100 010100 100100 010101 000111 010000 010100 011101 010010 010000 010101 010001 001001 010100 110101 ______ ______
```

(using `__` to represent the padding characters).

Now, grouping these by 8 instead of 6, we get

```
01000101 01001110 01010100 01010010 01000101 01000111 01000001 01000111 01010010 01000001 01010100 01001001 01010011 0101____ ________
  E        N        T        R        E        G        A        G        R        A        T        I        S        P
```

The important part is at the end, where there are some non-zero bits followed by padding. The Dart implementation is correctly determining that the padding provided doesn't make sense provided that the last four bits of the previous character do not decode to zeros.

As a result, the decoding of `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==` is ambiguous. Is it `ENTREGAGRATIS` or `ENTREGAGRATISP`? It's precisely this reason why the RFC states, "These pad bits MUST be set to zero by conforming encoders."

In fact, because of this, I'd argue that an implementation that decodes `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==` to `ENTREGAGRATIS` without complaint is problematic, because it's silently discarding non-zero bits.

The RFC-compliant encoding of `ENTREGAGRATIS` is `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJUw==`.

The RFC-compliant encoding of `ENTREGAGRATISP` is `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1A=`.

This further highlights the ambiguity of your input `RU5UUkVHQUdSQVRJU1==`, which matches neither.

I suggest you check your encoder to determine why it's providing you with non-compliant encodings, and make sure you're not losing information as a result.